# distribution of these values as a bar chart/histogram

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

In a MySQL database there's a table with a single numeric value column. I want to plot the distribution of these values as a bar chart/histogram with the following requirements:

there should be a maximum of N bars (intervals) in the chart
the width of each bar (x-axis range) should be uniform and the height of each bar should reflect the number of values in this interval.
the endpoints of the bar should occur at round numbers. I understand that this is a fairly vague requirement, but hopefully the following example will illustrate what I mean
the intervals should be contiguous, e.g. the next interval should start where the previous one ended
ideally it should be possible to retrieve the data with a single query
it's OK to have intervals with a count (y-axis value) of 0

Comment: `mysql` or `sql-server` ? Pick one!

Answer (score 1):

```
           // intervalCount is what I've referred to as "N"
  static Integer getRoundedIntervalSize(Double min, Double max, Integer 
  intervalCount) {
Number intervalSize = Math.ceil((max - min) / intervalCount)

Integer roundingScale = Math.log10(intervalSize) - 1
Number roundNearest = 10 ** roundingScale

// round up the interval size to the nearest roundNearest
Number intervalDelta = roundNearest - (intervalSize % roundNearest)
intervalSize + intervalDelta
```

}

Comment: @SanthoshAlukuri . . . It didn't seem necessary because `VisitId` is in the other table.  But I added it in for the filtering criteria.

Comment: @SanthoshAlukuri . . . I misread the question and thought you wanted both values but only from the most recent date.  Clearly, that is not your question.

Comment: @SanthoshAlukuri . . . I already adjusted the answer to handle each separately.